# Passing pointer to variadic arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments, function-pointers

I'm looking to pass a variable number of arguments by pointer to a callback function that is also referenced by pointer. Is there any way I can create a list of args that can be passed by reference?

Ex:

```
typedef struct MENUELEMENT
{
  void* OK_func; void* OK_args;
} menuElement_t;

menuElement_t* curMenuElement;

menuElement_t menu[] =
{
  //First Menu Element
  (void*)menuDisplayText, (void*)("Test", (char*)&lcdBuffer[0]) //menuDisplayText is a function that takes two arguments
  //Second Menu Element
  (void*)menuDisplayVal, (void*)&value[0] //menuDisplayVal is a function that takes one argument
};

void loop() //Main Loop - just an example of how the function pointed to by curMenuElement is executed
{
  curMenuElement = &menu[0];
  if(KP_OK)
  {
    (*reinterpret_cast<void (*)(...)>(curMenuElement->OK_func))(curMenuElement->OK_args); //General template for function pointed to at OK_func with OK_args
  }
}
```

So far this works well with one argument, however I cannot figure out how to pass a list of multiple arguments in the initialization of the struct variable. Is this even possible without having to use a builder function that uses va_list?

Comment: There's no C here. Just C++... and [what is `void main()`](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html)?.. and [why shouldn't you use it](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain3.html)?

Comment: It is illegal to cast function pointers to `void*`.

Comment: @JesseGood Indeed. In which day and age would the type of a lambda be `void *`? That would be one extremely confusing era!

Comment: @JesseGood: Absolutely true, although POSIX-conforming systems require function pointers and `void*` to be interchangeable as a consequence of the [`dlsym()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html)

Comment: FWIW - this is for an embedded system and just an example to illustrate conceptually what I am trying to accomplish. If you have any insight, rather than comments on stylistics, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Variadic functions accept parameters on the stack only.  The loop would have to know how many argument values are in the struct for a given function, then drop down to the assembler layer to manually push the values onto the stack, then call the current function, and then finally pop the values off of the stack after the function exits.  It is certainly doable, but it is a lot of work to do manually, and you lose compile-time safely.

You are better off just passing the struct itself, or at least its members, to each function and let them decide how to use the values as needed.  For example:

```
typedef void (*menuFunc)(void** args, int numArgs);

typedef struct MENUELEMENT
{
    menuFunc OK_func;
    int OK_num_args;
    void** OK_args;
} menuElement_t;
```

.

```
void menuDisplayText(void** args, int numArgs)
{
    ...
}

void menuDisplayVal(void** args, int numArgs)
{
    ...
}

void* menuDisplayTextArgs[] =
{
    "Test"
    &lcdBuffer[0]
};

menuElement_t menu[] =
{
  {&menuDisplayText, 2, menuDisplayTextArgs},
  {&menuDisplayVal, 1, &value[0]}
};
```

.

```
void loop()
{
    menuElement_t* curMenuElement = &menu[0];
    if (KP_OK)
    {
        curMenuElement->OK_func(curMenuElement->OK_args, curMenuElement->OK_num_args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "It is certainly doable" it would only be doable for a specific architecture and calling convention. it would not be portable

Comment: When dropping down to the assembly layer, you have to write platform-specific instructions. On 32-bit platforms, the only calling convention that supports variadic parameters is `cdecl` and that is a portable calling convention with a well-defined stack layout. On 64-bit platforms, there is only one calling convention available, but how it implements variadic parameters differs between AMD vs Intel, GCC vs VC++, etc. So yes, writing low-level code is not very portable...

Comment: ...  But there is no other way if you want to build up a function's parameter list dynamically, like the OP asked for.  Hense my suggestion to not even attempt it, but to re-write the code into something that is better supported by the language without resorting to low-level trickery, and let the compiler deal with platform issues.

Comment: Thanks for this - conceptually it's good, however the problem that I know face is that for each member of the menuElement struct, there are seven different functions and associated arguments that need to be defined multiplied by a few dozen menuElement elements. It would be ideal if I could declare these data within the struct itself (for code neatness) rather than outside the array. Thanks for this though, by declaring a void* for each member, I am able to pass that through with my original code!